# How should we find population of a species in an region

Tags: probability

I was reading about a considered a very general method. What we do is  go to a area where we want to find a population (let's say in a river),catch some  fishes to mark them (for simplicity let's say 20 , of course it is done with much bigger sample), then we throw them back in the river .Come back few days then again catch us same amount of fishes and if comes out to be 5 marked one again  we say the population is 80.

Now when look at as Bayesian problem ,we dont know the population but we are given that we marked p things and come back got k things of same mark , then find the population.Then for our method proves very unlikely(But of course for that i assumed that if had not done the experiment then each population has equal probability ,for example that their population is 5 and their population is in millions all have same same probability, maybe thats why its faulty).

But if i look at it lets say i picked one fourth of their population, then when i come back(assuming they have been mixed throughly in the population which i think should be a faulty assumption), when i find expectation of no of marked one in k things is $\frac{k}{4}$ , for a big population getting no of expected thimgs  should have a high probability,this may support the method.

This is only when you look it that way which is not very satisfying .I want to know what assumptions do we take , how do we prove mathematically above method is accurate for a big population and big sample space?I would prefer if we can look at it  as random walk probem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the "Mark and recapture" method (or "Lincoln - Petersen").

Let's assume we have:

N = Number of fish in the population

n = Number of fish marked on the first catch

K = Number of fish captured on the second catch

k = Number of recaptured fish that were marked

then

$N = \frac{n*K}{k}$

Comment: My question is not what method it is , rather why is this a good method  to measure the population .